# setting up vim project space with 4 different code but related code bases

Tags: c++, vim, workflow, production, codebase

I'm a novice vim user who really likes vim and wants to take it to the next step in my development workflow.

I have 4 different C/C++ code bases which are compiled using 3 different compilers. Each of the code bases has its own project and makefiles for the compilers. I keep the compilers open to compile the different projects. Two code bases are for firmware of a device, one code base is for a library and the last code base is for a cross platform desktop app that uses the library to talk to the device.

I mainly use vim for my code editing, and right now I have several different vim windows that I keep open, i.e. one per code base. I exit the vim editors a lot to open different code files, which is very unproductive. I often have to look up functions in different files within the same code base. I often have to switch between code bases because the software compiled from one code base processes data generated by a program from another code base and I have to double check defines and such.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to organize this using vim? How does an expert vim user set up his development workflow to work with multiple related code bases within the same vim environment and how does he/she navigate the code bases efficiently?

Comment: Vim is just a very powerful and lightweight editor it doesn't have to do explicitly with code navigation. Normally, this happens implicitly in corporation with some other piece of software (e.g., ctags). As far as it concern your question, IMHO is primarily opinion based. Experts usually organize their development environment in a very custom way that effectively maximizes their workflow.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based - I'm looking for a best practice here, or at least some useful suggestions on packages that I could use that would allow me to set up a productive environment within vim.

Answer (score 0):

If your projects are related, and files from one project are referred to in another, I would recommend to open them all in one GVIM instance. I personally often use *tab pages* to segregate different projects within one Vim instance, but Vim (together with your favorite plugins) is so flexible in this regard that virtually any workflow can be reflected.

For a more precise comment and recommendation, your question is missing details like:

- How (through which plugin) do you open project files / recently opened files?
- Is your *current working directory* set to the project root, and does this matter to your workflow?
- How is your window layout, do you have any sidebars, and how do you organize your files (buffer list, minimized splits, arg list, etc.)?

There are some blog posts about how individuals have set up their Vim environments, but these naturally are bound to personal preferences and the particular programming environment. So, use them for inspiration, but be aware that there's no perfect recipe, and you'll have to find your own, personal way.